# Invalid variable name ' ${DBHost}'

Tags: sql, database, robotframework

I am trying to connect to data base by creating a new table, When ever i try i am getting Invalid host name.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary
Library    OperatingSystem
Library  DatabaseLibrary

Suite Setup     Connect To Database     pymysql     ${DBHost}   ${DBUser}   ${DBPass}   ${DBName}   ${DBPort}
Suite Teardown  Disconnect From Database


*** Variables ***

 ${DBHost}      EMB-BAN-810
 ${DBUser}      root
 ${DBPass}      Sql@123
 ${DBName}      robot_db
 ${DBPort}      3306


*** Test Cases ***
Create Person table
    ${output}= Execute SQL String  Create table person(id integer,first_name varchar(20),Last_name varchar(20))
    log to console  ${output}
    Should be equal as Strings   ${output}   None
```

## `(venv) PS D:\pythonProject1> robot testcase\DataBase.robot
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'D:\pythonProject1\testcase\DataBase.robot' on line 12: Setting variable ' ${DBHost}' failed: Invalid variable name ' ${DBHost}'.
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'D:\pythonProject1\testcase\DataBase.robot' on line 13: Setting variable ' ${DBUser}' failed: Invalid variable name ' ${DBUser}'.
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'D:\pythonProject1\testcase\DataBase.robot' on line 14: Setting variable ' ${DBPass}' failed: Invalid variable name ' ${DBPass}'.
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'D:\pythonProject1\testcase\DataBase.robot' on line 15: Setting variable ' ${DBName}' failed: Invalid variable name ' ${DBName}'.
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'D:\pythonProject1\testcase\DataBase.robot' on line 16: Setting variable ' ${DBPort}' failed: Invalid variable name ' ${DBPort}'.

## DataBase

Create Person table                                                   | FAIL |
Parent suite setup failed:
Variable '${DBHost}' not found.
`

Comment: You have redundant spaces before variable names.

Comment: Clarify the question.